# crash with Fatal - unhandled exception - native android error

Tags: android

I am getting a crash on htc one when running an app and entering the sub section;
what does it mean  "Fatal - unhandled exception - native android",
and why I am getting a crash?

I am getting this in the monitor:

```
03-08 14:57:47.445: E/MP-Decision(2946): Update arg 1
03-08 14:57:47.583: E/rumble-sdk(30017): Fatal - unhandled exception - native android
03-08 14:57:47.583: W/System.err(30017): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 1
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(AbsListView.java:2553)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.ListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(ListView.java:3946)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$ListItemAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:2484)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6104)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6065)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:22414)
03-08 14:57:47.586: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6048)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6002)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22326)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5988)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5855)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:22265)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5838)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5817)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22223)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5782)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:317)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1214)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3139)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3981)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
03-08 14:57:47.587: W/System.err(30017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017): uncaught exception:
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 1
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(AbsListView.java:2553)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.ListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(ListView.java:3946)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$ListItemAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:2484)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6104)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6065)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:22414)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6048)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6002)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22326)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5988)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5855)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:22265)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5838)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5817)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22223)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5782)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:317)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1214)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3139)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3981)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
03-08 14:57:47.602: I/art(30017): Starting a blocking GC HeapTrim
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 1 03-08 14:57:47.588: E/rumble-sdk(30017): at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Answer (score 1):

Read through the crash logs and you will be able to spot the error.

```
Invalid index 8, size is 1
```

Whats happening is that you are trying to get an object at index 8 however the size of your array is 1 so its returning null.

Comment: thank you much! but the strange thing is that I am getting this only on htc one marshmallow...why can it be?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is interesting for you:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 1
```

Apparently you are trying to get 9th item of a single-item-sized array somewhere.

Comment: but the strange thing is that I am getting this only on htc one marshmallow...why can it be?